# How to get a filename without extension in ant

Tags: ant, filenames

I know how to get the basename for a file with java's ANT build tool, but in this case I want to change the name of a file to include a build version number. Unfortunately the file's name gets set in another ant script (from the android system) which I am importing and I'm not able to set the property for that file or the imported script will complain that the property should not be set already. Thus, if i have a property holding MyApp-release.apk and I want to change the value to MyApp-release-1.10.apk how would I do this? I know I can put the 1.10 at the start of the filename with basename and that's probably what I will do, but I'd rather do it the other way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Form http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/basename.html:

> Task to determine the basename of a specified file, optionally minus a
>   specified suffix.

```
<basename property="cmdname" file="D:/usr/local/foo.exe"
          suffix=".exe"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, read the doc wrong, thought suffix was to generate a suffix to append a suffix to the basename